# SQL inner vs left join question

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a very badly performing sql query.  I tracked it down to the INNER JOIN performed on the table.  Changing this to LEFT join significantly increases performance (from 6 min to 20 sec) - now i know the 2 are not equiv, but... here is what i am asking

```
SELECT * 
  FROM SomeTable ST
  JOIN BigTable BT ON BT.SomeID = ST.SomeID 
                  AND BT.Something = ST.Something 
                  AND BT.AnotherValue = '123'
```

Since the join has additional criteria (and something=something) -- is changing this to a left join producing the same results - but MUCH faster?

The results returned are the same using LEFT/INNER with left being significantly faster...

Comment: This is bizarre, since in most cases `INNER JOIN` performs better. An `OUTER JOIN` must return rows even where there isn't a match. Are you sure there's not more to this than the join type?

Comment: YUP, im confused as ever - the logical reads drops by millions (many millions)

Comment: can you post execution plans for both?

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan to see if anything else is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: Show us: execution plans + indexes on the tables.

Comment: Sounds like an indexing or statistics problem.

Comment: I was attempting to include the execution plan - but its WAY WAY WAY long.  I have checked my indexes and I have indexes for all values specified in the JOIN

Comment: @user822150: Index on `SomeID` and `Something` is different to index on `(SomeId, Something)` which is different to index on `(Something, SomeID)`.

Comment: I have made the same query in my SQL server with both inner and left join. Both query's return the same results - left join has no meaning.Checking the plan's of both queries I saw they are completely identical

Answer (score 2):

It looks like doing the inner join the other way around would give a better performance...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    BigTable AS BT
INNER JOIN
    SomeTable AS ST
ON
    BT.AnotherValue = '123'
AND
    BT.SomeID = ST.SomeID 
AND
    BT.Something = ST.Something
```

or with subquery

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM BigTable WHERE AnotherValue = '123') AS BT
INNER JOIN
    SomeTable AS ST
AND
    BT.SomeID = ST.SomeID 
AND
    BT.Something = ST.Something
```

Also, make sure the `BigTable.AnotherValue` is properly indexed.

Answer (score 0):

While you're getting the same results from both joins its important to understand that a left join is different from an inner join.

> A left join will take all rows from
>   the left table even if there are no
>   matches in the right table.

[SQL LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) vs. [SQL INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

So your data just happens to be produced in a manner that is identical given the two different joins.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM SomeTable ST
  JOIN BigTable BT ON BT.SomeID = ST.SomeID 
                  AND BT.Something = ST.Something 
                  AND BT.AnotherValue = '123'
```

How about this:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   SomeTable
      INNER JOIN
   BigTable
      ON SomeTable.PreferedPrimaryKey = BigTable.PreferAForeignKey
      AND SomeTable.SomethingThatIsIndexedAndPreferableNumeric = BigTable.SomethingThatIsIndexedAndPreferableNumeric 
WHERE
   BigTable.AnotherValue = '123'
```

Check your indexes and make sure your criteria for the second part of the join isn't a non-indexed character string.

Comment: You don't use a w3schools as a trusted source. Never. That's what they told me.

Comment: I don't know where you heard this about w3schools, but sql joins have been around for decades and implemented in several databases. They probably got this right.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` is different to `LEFT JOIN` but they don't always give different results. If every row of the left side table has a match in the right side table, then they are equivalent.

Comment: I agree, that's what I stated.